# New AWS EC2 cannot install Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

Today 12 April 2020. Region `Singapore` I have only `a1` type and when I use `a1.large` I am unable to find docker package. I am suspect that it is not `amd64` therefore I can not find the package

```
# lscpu
Architecture:          aarch64
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Model:                 3
BogoMIPS:              166.66
Flags:                 fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
```

I had tried `aarch64` in the `/etc/apt/source.list` file here is a error

```
# apt update
Ign:1 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/binary-aarch64/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'aarch64'
```

[image: AWS a1 effect]

**Question:**
Do I need to start `compiling` by myself from scratch!?

Comment: Experimenting with `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh`, but I am open for new approach or new information

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time. I have to use `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh`

Comment: So the problem is sorted, right? Or do you need any assistance?

Comment: I think so. Since `docker` works fine up until now. I freak out by the wording `do not use in production`

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon Linux with Docker pre-installed, use the ECS optimised AMIs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html